# How to combine filtering with lazyloading in fancytree?

Tags: javascript, fancytree

Is there a way to both enable the filtering and lazy load the nodes in [fancytree](https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/wiki)? I expect the behaviour like this:

- the user can walk in the tree with each node loaded when clicked. This is supported by lazy loading feature
- when the user puts something into the filter input, the API call to the search server is executed and fancytree receives the elements with their parents in a tree. Fancytree is rendering the elements

Comment: Any news? Did you find a solution?